# regex string extension

Tags: c#, regex, extension-methods

I wrote some `string`-extensions:

```
public static class RegexStringExtensions
{
    public static string PatternReplace(
        this string seed, string pattern, 
        Func<string, string> outPattern)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(seed, pattern, s => outPattern(s.Groups[1].Value));
    }

    public static string PatternReplace(
        this string seed, string pattern, 
        Func<string, string, string> outPattern)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(seed, pattern, s => outPattern(s.Groups[1].Value, s.Groups[2].Value));
    }
    public static string PatternReplace(
        this string seed, string pattern, 
        Func<string, string, string, string> outPattern)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(seed, pattern, s => outPattern(s.Groups[1].Value, s.Groups[2].Value, s.Groups[3].Value));
    }
    public static string PatternReplace(
        this string seed, string pattern, 
        Func<string, string, string, string, string> outPattern)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(seed, pattern, s => outPattern(s.Groups[1].Value, s.Groups[2].Value, s.Groups[3].Value, s.Groups[4].Value));
    }
}
```

with those, I could handle a replacement for regex-pattern and work with the groups more in C#-way like (just an easy example):

```
string val = 
    "abcdef".PatternReplace(@"(ab)(cd)(ef)", (s,t,u) => u + string.Concat(s.Reverse()));
// result is "efba"
```

I think it's not that nice, to have so many overloads since I could have like 10 groups or something.
Any idea how I could make this a bit nicer?
For now, it'd work with up to 4 parameters, but with also 4 overloads.

Comment: What's bad with those overloads? If you need an extra parameter you just add it to your lambda, no need to also change method name (`PatternReplace1`, `PatternReplace2`, etc? nooo)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti would be nice to have something like `params` for generics. would save me a lot of code...- so you wouldn't change anything and just go with e.g. 10 overloads?

Comment: Honestly I'd stop with 2 overloads (3 at maximum). At the calling point a lambda with so many parameters will be (IMO) pretty hard to read and a _traditional_ approach preferable. Well, it's just my POV. Note that nothing stops you to have an extra `Func<string[], string>` overload (sacrifyng readability)

Comment: `a lambda with so many parameters will be (IMO) pretty hard to read` good point! Mh I think I will go with only 4 parameters. I don't think I will ever use more than 4 groups... otherwise I simply will use the `Regex`-class if I got more than 4 params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not saying I like this but you could reuse the longest overload for the shorter ones. Here I took the one that takes three parameters.

```
public static string PatternReplace(
    this string seed, 
    string pattern,
    Func<string, string> outPattern
)
{
    return seed.PatternReplace(pattern, (x, y, z) => outPattern(x));
}

public static string PatternReplace(
    this string seed, 
    string pattern,
    Func<string, string, string> outPattern
)
{
    return seed.PatternReplace(pattern, (x, y, z) => outPattern(x, y));
}
```

---

Here's another small experiment with **C# 7** where you could use anonymous tuples with only one method. But actually you could return a tuple in you current solution too.

```
public static class RegexStringExtensions
{   
    public static string PatternReplace(
        this string seed, 
        string pattern,
        Func<(string, string, string), string> outPattern
    )
    {
        return Regex.Replace(
            seed, 
            pattern, 
            m => outPattern((
                m.Groups[1].Value, 
                m.Groups[2].Value, 
                m.Groups[3].Value)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string val = "abcdef".PatternReplace(
    @"(ab)(cd)(ef)", 
    t => t.Item1 + string.Concat(t.Item2.Reverse())
);
```

Comment: wow, okay, that's an approach I could experiment with. Didn't know working with s.th. like `Func<(string, string, string), string>` (but first, need to check for C#7)